# JMSXGroupID/correlation-id to queue messages on stomp client doesn't seem to work

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp

I was trying to queue messages to the same consumer using stomp-js on a node server.

Producer:

```
producer.send({'JMSXGroupID':JMSXGroupID, 'destination':confMgr.getConfig("jmsqueue.destination"), 'body':JSON.stringify(msg), 'persistent':'true'}, false);
```

Consumer:

```
client.on('message', function(message) {
    client.ack(message.headers['message-id']);
})
```

I was sending two messages using the same JMSXGroupID and it seems that the the client processess both the messages in parallel rather than processing message1 and ack'ing it and going ahead to process message2 and then ack'ing message2. I tried using 'correlation-id' and it doesn't seem to work either. Can anyone suggest a better way?
Thank you in advance,
Chandra.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using this stomp-js lib (correct me if I'm wrong): https://github.com/benjaminws/stomp-js

Message groups are supported by ActiveMQ using Stomp, so you are most likely getting the messages in order. Processing them in order requires you to somehow process each message synchronously on the client, which is rather simple when you can controll how many threads that the listener will run in. This might not be as easy with java script.  which is not

From what I can see, the lib you are using is not the most well documented, the only setting you could tweak that might (I have not tried it!), is to alter the prefetch size to one.

```
var headers = {
  destination: '/queue/test_stomp',
  ack: 'client',
  'activemq.prefetchSize': '1'
};
```

It might be the case that this lib still starts eagerly directly to fetch the next message, but you might want to test it.

On the other hand, you might as well want to re design the application to be sequence independent, since you are running node.js and java script. It's always better to have a sequence independence with messaging, since you are able to optimize performance a lot better and can avoid synchronous behaviours.

I don't know what you did try to achieve with correlation id, but that header is used to correlate a request with a reply, which is not the case here.